# .htaccess rewrite URL - and playground

Tags: .htaccess

**I have the following url:**

```
http://example.com/reviews/view-course?courseID=933
```

**Which I'd like to show as:**

```
http://example.com/933/somethingDynamicHere
```

**This is what I'm trying but I get a blank page:**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /reviews/view-course?courseID=$1 [L]
```

Is there a better way to do this? Also, as importantly, is there a playground where I can try changes and see results on the fly so I can learn about this more?

**UPDATE**

I also have html5 Angular rewrite rules in the file as well so total is as follows:

```
#angular html5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /reviews/index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is not matching your desired pretty URI. Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/[^/]+/?$ reviews/view-course?courseID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! But that's not working for me - I've updated question as I guess what I've added might change things slightly

Comment: Make sure this rule is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line. Also tell what error are you getting?